# Possible causes for slow mahapps metro dialog opening due to PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm investigating why opening a dialog in a mahapps application is much slower than the other dialogs in the same application, but I'm having trouble making progress, or even knowing where to look.

It's a dialog that contains a collection of options, when I run a profiler on the code all it gives me is that the majority of the work is happening inside the PresentationFramework dll, and a lot of the time is taken up by a PropertyGrid.

Sorry that this is a bit vague, I'm mostly just looking for direction on what sort of thing I should investigate when trying to debug something like this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show the implementation of the dialog. Are there many items in the collection or just a few? How do you display them? This could be a XAML (layout) related rendering issue. Do you use virtualization?

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window. If you change all debugging levels to verbose, you'll see in Output window a detailed report on each issue or binding error you have when the dialog starts.

I also recommend VSColorOutput extension - it will add colors to messages in output and will help you spotting errors.